# access the properties and their values of an object dynamically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, object

I wanna access the properties and their values of an object dynamically, the scenario is:

```js
const SoldeN = {
    1:4,
}
const SoldeN_1 = {
    2:5,
}
const soldes = [
  { formula: '=SoldeN("1")',value:0},
  { formula: '=SoldeN_1("2")',value:0},
  { formula: '=SoldeN_1("1")+SoldeN_1("2")',value:0},
];
```

What I've tried so far:

```js
const getProperty = string => string.match(/\(.*?\)/g).map(x => x.replace(/[(")]/g, ''))
const getObject = string => string.match(/[=+](.*?)\(/g).map(x => x.replace(/[=(+]/g, ''))
console.log(soldes.map(solde=>[getObject(solde.formula),getProperty(solde.formula)]))
```

```js
[
  [["SoldeN"], ["1"]],
  [["SoldeN_1"], ["2"]],
  [
    ["SoldeN_1", "SoldeN_1"],
    ["1", "2"],
  ],
];
```

Till now Everything is ok, **but** To get the value of an object dynamically based on property I used this function:

```js
const getPropertyValue = (obj, prop) => obj[prop];
getPropertyValue('SoldeN','1')
//'o'
```

It gives me `'o'` instead of `1`, I know If I've passed the reference of an object it bring its value; but to get it dynamically I've to pass the actual name of an object which is *string,* not the *object reference*.
The expected Result would be:

```js
result = [
  { formula: '=SoldeN("1")',value:4},
  { formula: '=SoldeN_1("2")',value:5},
  { formula: '=SoldeN_1("1")+SoldeN_1("2")',value:9},
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just put your data inside an object and map the data inside loop?
There is no need to use `eval` at all.

```js
const data = {
    SoldeN: {
        1: 4,
    },
    SoldeN_1: {
        2: 5,
    },
};

const soldes = [
    { formula: '=SoldeN("1")', value: 0 },
    { formula: '=SoldeN_1("2")', value: 0 },
    { formula: '=SoldeN("1")+SoldeN_1("2")', value: 0 },
];

const getProperty = string =>
    string.match(/\(.*?\)/g).map(x => x.replace(/[(")]/g, ""));
const getObject = string =>
    string.match(/[=+](.*?)\(/g).map(x => x.replace(/[=(+]/g, ""));

const output = soldes.map(solde => {
    const objs = getObject(solde.formula);
    const props = getProperty(solde.formula);
    const newVal = objs.reduce((carry, item, idx) => {
        carry += data[item][props[idx]];
        return carry;
    }, solde.value);
    return {
        ...solde,
        value: newVal,
    };
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Perfect and safer than using `eval`

Comment: @TAHERElMehdi, I think you should change accepted answer to my answer because I think `eval()` is not necessary at all. It may help the future readers to find a proper answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, anyway your answer is still the best in terms of safety and Security Concerns!

Answer (score 1):

You can [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) the object name.

```js
const SoldeN = { 1:4 };
const getPropertyValue = (obj, prop) => eval(obj)[prop];
console.log(getPropertyValue('SoldeN','1'));
```

But be cautious as it is risky! If bad code can get into the `eval` argument, things can happen.

Comment: Thanks for answer, Yes I know it is dangerous to use eval!

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of javascript `eval` method to execute the expression.

**Logic**

- Loop through nodes in `soldes`.
- Replace all `"="` with empty string. `"("` with `"["` and `")"` with `"]"`.
- This will mmake the expression `=SoldeN("1")+SoldeN_1("2")` to `SoldeN["1"]+SoldeN_1["2"]`.
- Evaluating this will give you the expected result.

```js
const SoldeN = {
  1: 4,
};
const SoldeN_1 = {
  2: 5,
};
const soldes = [
  { formula: '=SoldeN("1")', value: 0 },
  { formula: '=SoldeN_1("2")', value: 0 },
  { formula: '=SoldeN("1")+SoldeN_1("2")', value: 0 },
];
const getValue = (formula) => eval(formula.replaceAll("=", "").replaceAll("(", "[").replaceAll(")", "]"));
const result = soldes.map((item) => ({
  formula: item.formula,
  value: getValue(item.formula)
}));
console.log(result);
```

**Please Note** Error handling is considered as out of scope.

Comment: A smart and effective approach to solving this problem!